# Yii: handling login without a login page

Tags: yii

I'm working with a server-based authentication, so I'm attempting to implement a custom login system in Yii. To learn the system, I tried to create a dummy authentication class that would automatically log in a user. I included the class in the config, but I can't figure out how to log users in.

Is there a way to automatically log in on the first use of the application (eg as a session is created?) Or is there some better way of achieving this?

The base of this is a custom authentication class:

```
class MyAuthentication 
    extends CApplicationComponent
    implements IUserIdentity {

    private $_username = '';
    private $_authenticated = False;
    ...
    public function authenticate()
    {
        $this->_username = 'exampleUser'; 
        $this->_authenticated = True; 
        return True;
    }

    public function getIsAuthenticated()
    {
        return $this->_authenticated;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my authentication was based on a server-side variable, I was able to use the `expression` feature of the accessRules array to check if that variable was true. I wrote a custom class to help:

```
class User
{

  public function is_authenticated() 
  {
    return True;
  }

}
```

And updated my rules to use an expression check instead of a user check, [as described by the documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAccessControlFilter):

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array('index','view', 'new'),
            'expression'=>'User::is_authenticated()',
            ...
```

Answer (score 1):

seems like you're close. something like this should work re your example:

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    private $_username = '';
    private $_authenticated = FALSE;

    public function authenticate()
    {
        $this->_username = 'exampleUser'; 
        $this->_authenticated = TRUE; 
        return $this->_authenticated;
    }
    public function getIsAuthenticated()
    {
        return $this->_authenticated;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a filter for Controller and check the user was authenticated or not. If not, authenticate a user.